# how can i prevent my videos from being downloaded on odoo e-learning?

Tags: security, video, download, odoo, vimeo

I'm having a major problem with the odoo e-learning module. When I add the video link (youtube or drive), the user can retrieve the link by inspecting the page.

But when I use vimeo and set the video as "Hide in vimeo", the user manages to get the link, but this time he can't access the video.
Isn't there another way to prevent the user from downloading the video?

Answer (score 0):

Try using blob urls... but since they will be an address for a memory value in the browser, the user will still be able to retrieve the original video url from the request response.

It will be very tricky to accomplish to be honest